# i want array in structure and copy only one character

Tags: c, pointers, arraylist

first, see this code plz.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 3
struct body
{
    char p[3];
    char v[3];
    char a[3];
    double radius;
    double mass;
};
struct body bodies[N];

int main() {
    int a, b;
    for(a = 0; a < 1; a++) {
        for(b =0; b < 1; b++) {
            strncpy(&bodies[a].p[b] , "asd", sizeof(3));
            strncpy(&bodies[a].v[b] , "bbb", sizeof("bbb"));
            strncpy(&bodies[a].a[b] , "ccc", sizeof("ccc"));
            printf("\n1. = %s\n",&bodies[a].p[b]);
            printf("\n2. = %s\n",&bodies[a].v[b]);
            printf("\n3. = %s\n",&bodies[a].a[b]);
        }
        bodies[a].mass = 0;
        bodies[a].radius= 1.0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and result is

1. = asdbbbccc
2. = bbbccc
3. = ccc

i want one char in one line ! 
for example

1. = asd
2. = bbb
3. = ccc

why print like that ? T.T
is that pointer problem?????

Help me ~

Comment: None of "asd", "bbb" and "ccc" are one char! What do you acutally want? By the way, accessing out-of-range is bad and will invoke *undefined behavior*.

Comment: Ironically, `sizeof(3)` is 4.

Comment: Your usage of `sizeof` looks weird. The third argument of `strncpy` should be the size of destination buffer, not the size of what to be copied. `sizeof(3)` is worse.

Comment: Use `%3s` instead of `%s`, which requires null-terminated string to be passed, to print the non-null-terminated sequences of characters in the arrays.

Comment: This is not a question of undefined behavior. Something else is wrong.

Comment: You're confusing `sizeof` with `strlen`.  None of the `sizeof` uses in your code are correct.  You're also writing past the end of your arrays, since you forgot to allocate space for the trailing null byte.

Comment: OMG thanks. it was really fool question. .... thanks to every answers !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
struct body
{
    char p[3];
    char v[3];
    char a[3];
    double radius;
    double mass;
};
```

C strings are [null terminated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string), and that means they need an extra null character `'\0'` to denote the end of the string, so if you want to store a 3 character string, you need to allocate 4 characters to accommodate the extra null terminator.  Try this instead:

```
struct body
{
    char p[4];
    char v[4];
    char a[4];
    double radius;
    double mass;
};
```

Comment: This only addresses some of the problems with the code.

Answer (score 0):

> and result is
>
> 1. = asdbbbccc
> 2. = bbbccc

**Reason:**

this comes as a result due to some factors in your code...

1. generally, a character array `char a[3]` can hold two characters at `a[0]` and `a[1]` along with one terminating `'\0'` character at `a[size-1]` i.e, `a[3-1]`
2. in your code you are trying to overwrite the null or `'\0'` character by assigning an array of size 3 with all 3 letters
3. In a structure it's members are stored in sequential order therefore... 
    `char p[3];`, `char v[3];`, `char a[3];` are in sequential order,
4. so when you try to print `printf("\n1. = %s\n",&bodies[a].p[0]);`, this prints starting from `bodies[a].p[0]` to `'\0'` character which is not present in any of your strings.therefore, `printf()` continues to print the strings             `bodies[a].v`,`bodies[a].a` and till it encounters `'\0'` which is undefined.
5. similarly this happens when you try to print the second string `printf("\n1. = %s\n",&bodies[a].v[0]);`... it continues to print `bodies[a].a` and till it encounters `'\0'` which is undefined :(

---

**Solution:**

To avoid this **provide space for** `'\0'` **character** and don't over write it... this way :

```
struct body
{
    char p[4]; //space for 3 letters along with one '\0' character
    char v[4];
    char a[4];
    double radius;
    double mass;
};
```

---

And **one more problem** in your code is that `sizeof(3)=4` because, `3` is an integer and in your system  int occupies `4` bytes. But, size of your string is `3` in your code.to resolve this try only giving `3` instead of `sizeof(3)` as argument

---

putting all together your **code** would be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#define N 3
struct body
{
    char p[4]; //size = 4
    char v[4];
    char a[4];
    double radius;
    double mass;
};
struct body bodies[N];

int main() {
    int a,b;
    for(a = 0; a < 1; a++) {
        for(b =0; b < 1; b++) {
            strncpy(&bodies[a].p[b] , "asd", 3); //size = 3 bytes
            strncpy(&bodies[a].v[b] , "bbb", 3); //size = 3 bytes
            strncpy(&bodies[a].a[b] , "ccc", 3); //size = 3 bytes
            printf("\n1. = %s\n",&bodies[a].p[0]);
            printf("\n2. = %s\n",&bodies[a].v[0]);
            printf("\n3. = %s\n",&bodies[a].a[0]);
        }
        bodies[a].mass = 0;
        bodies[a].radius= 1.0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

**output**:

```
1. = asd

2. = bbb

3. = ccc
```

Answer (score -4):

You can use `malloc` with C string (`char *`) to get the result you want:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 3
struct body
{
    char * p;
    char v[3];
    char a[3];
    double radius;
    double mass;
};
struct body bodies[N];

int main() {
    int a, b;
    for(a = 0; a < 1; a++) {
        for(b =0; b < 1; b++) {
            bodies[a].p = malloc(3);
            strncpy(bodies[a].p , "asd", sizeof(3));
            printf("\n1. = %s\n",bodies[a].p);

        }
        bodies[a].mass = 0;
        bodies[a].radius= 1.0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The whole program will become:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#define N 3
struct body
{
    char * p;
    char * v;
    char * a;
    double radius;
    double mass;
};
struct body bodies[N];

int main() {
    int a, b;
    for(a = 0; a < 1; a++) {
        for(b =0; b < 1; b++) {
            bodies[a].p = malloc(3);
            bodies[a].v = malloc(3);
            bodies[a].a = malloc(3);
            strncpy(bodies[a].p , "asd", sizeof(3));
            strncpy(bodies[a].v , "bbb", sizeof("bbb"));
            strncpy(bodies[a].a , "ccc", sizeof("ccc"));
            printf("\n1. = %s\n",bodies[a].p);
            printf("\n2. = %s\n",bodies[a].v);
            printf("\n3. = %s\n",bodies[a].a);

        }
        bodies[a].mass = 0;
        bodies[a].radius= 1.0;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Test output

```
1. = asd

2. = bbb

3. = ccc

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: This doesn't even address some of the most serious problems in the code, such as the fact that none of the `sizeof` instance make sense (as was mentioned in the comments, `sizeof(3)` is probably 4, and the others are probably either 4 or 8).  The code you posted is buggy and should not be used.